# Angular frontend not sending authorization cookie when requesting across origins (even with withCredentials)

Tags: angular, spring, authentication

Okay so I've been really stuck on this issue all day.

I have an Angular frontend hosted locally on `localhost:4200` and a Spring Boot backend on `localhost:8080`.

I can hit the `localhost:8080/api/login` endpoint from the Angular application successfully and I get a Set-Cookie header back. Here is the response from hitting `/login`

> [image]

The issue is that when making subsequent calls, for example to `localhost:8080/api/test`, I receive a 401. Seemingly due to the Cookie not being sent with the request. Here is what the request/response looks like

> >! [image]

Some important findings/considerations that I can give as well is that

1. When hitting the /login endpoint and then the /test endpoint via Postman, everything works perfectly.
2. If I hit the /login endpoint and then the /test endpoint via the Angular project with a Webpack proxy configured, it works perfectly (ie. Make the requests to localhost:4200/api/login and then tell Webpack to internally forward that to localhost:8080). Due to this, I assume that the issue is somehow related to CORS. Because it seems that when the browser thinks the requests are being made to localhost:4200 (ie. The same domain), it sends the cookies as expected

Answer (score 0):

> You try it

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        Filter.super.init(filterConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, authorization, Content-Type, Authorization, credential, X-XSRF-TOKEN");

        String method = request.getMethod();

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(method)) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, resp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        Filter.super.destroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have my CORS policy set very similarly to that, unfortunately it doesnt work